# Python - Referencing lists in functions

Tags: python

Needless to say the following code does not work and the fault or problem seems to be that the function does not access or recognise the list [cards]. On the other hand if I place the list [cards] within the function, the code works perfectly. I had assumed that variables placed in the main code were global, and variables declared in a function were just local.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import random

cards = ['A︎♣︎︎', '2︎♣︎︎', '3︎♣︎︎', '4︎♣︎︎', '5︎♣︎︎', '6︎♣︎︎', '7︎♣︎︎', '8︎♣︎︎', '9︎♣︎︎', '10︎♣︎︎', 'J︎♣︎︎', 'Q︎♣︎︎',
         'K︎♣︎︎', 'A♠︎', '2♠︎', '3♠︎', '4♠︎', '5♠︎', '6♠︎', '7♠︎', '8♠︎', '9♠︎', '10♠︎', 'J♠︎',
         'Q♠︎', 'K♠︎', 'A︎♥︎', '2︎♥︎', '3︎♥︎', '4︎♥︎', '5︎♥︎', '6︎♥︎', '7︎♥︎', '8︎♥︎', '9︎♥︎', '10︎♥︎',
         'J︎♥︎', 'Q︎♥︎', 'K︎♥︎', 'A︎♦︎︎', '2︎♦︎︎', '3︎♦︎︎', '4︎♦︎︎', '5︎♦︎︎', '6︎♦︎︎', '7︎♦︎︎', '8︎♦︎︎', '9︎♦︎︎',
         '10︎♦︎︎', 'J︎♦︎︎', 'Q︎♦︎︎', 'K︎♦︎︎']

# define function


def sort_cards(hand):

    temp = []
    for n in range(0, 7):
        temp.append(cards.index(str(hand[n])))

    # sort cards
    temp.sort()
    hand = []

    # fetch card according to index and assign to hand
    for c in temp:
        hand.append(cards[c])

    return hand


# copy cards list to working list

rem_cards = cards

# initiate players card list

player1 = []
player2 = []
player3 = []

# define variable
# 7 cards per player

deal = 7

while deal != 0:

    # get a card from rem_cards and assign to player1
    card = rem_cards[random.randint(0, len(rem_cards) - 1)]
    player1.append(card)
    # remove card from deck
    rem_cards.remove(card)

    card = rem_cards[random.randint(0, len(rem_cards) - 1)]
    player2.append(card)
    rem_cards.remove(card)

    card = rem_cards[random.randint(0, len(rem_cards) - 1)]
    player3.append(card)
    rem_cards.remove(card)

    deal -= 1


print(sort_cards(player1))
print(sort_cards(player2))
print(sort_cards(player3))
print("No of cards left in the deck is ", len(rem_cards))
```

Any suggestions or is my concept just wrong?

Comment: what does 'not work' mean? do you get an error or unexpected output?

Comment: If you wish to use global variable inside function you should declare that variable in function body with `global` keyword

Comment: Just a tip: It's probably cleaner to use `random.choice` rather than indexing with `random.randint(0, len(rem_cards) - 1)`

Comment: Or `random.sample`, since you want several random items at once.

Comment: One suggestion, unrelated to the issue you're having (which the answers below seem to have addressed): Your `sort_cards` function could be dramatically simplified to `hand.sort(key=cards.index)` (or maybe `return sorted(hand, key=cards.index)` if you need to copy it rather than sorting in place).

Comment: @Pugwash I like your cards, nice try

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at your comments:

```
# copy cards list to working list

rem_cards = cards
```

This code *does not* make a copy of the list, it creates another *name*, under which the original list could be accessed. Whenever you modify `rem_cards`, `cards` is modified. Thus, `rem_cards.remove(card)` actually *removes* the card from `cards`!

If you want to copy the list, use [`copy.[deep]copy`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html):

```
import copy

# copy cards list to working list

rem_cards = copy.deepcopy(cards) # if cards could contain other lists
rem_cards = copy.copy(cards) # create a simple shallow copy
rem_cards = cards[:] # you may create shallow copies without the copy module
```

Comment: No need for `deepcopy`.

Comment: or create a copy like this: `rem_cards = cards[:]`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, right you are, this is just a precaution in case the list will once contain other lists

Comment: rem_cards = copy.copy(cards) - solved it. I was just looking at the wrong problem duh!

Comment: @ForceBru Then I think you should explain that. Most of the time, you do not need a deep copy anyway.

Comment: @Pugwash See Juraj Bezručka comment. No need for the `copy` module at all.

Comment: true - rem_cards = cards[:] - works as well!

Answer (score 0):

This also will solve your problem without using copy.deepcopy

```
rem_cards = cards[:]
```

Comment: Probably OP wants deep copy.

Comment: @direprobs Why does OP want a deep copy?

Comment: @direprobs no need of deep copy list items are string

Answer (score 0):

```
rem_cards = cards
```

does not copy the list, but just creates an alias. It should be

```
rem_cards = list(cards)
```